# Excel VSTO addin: appvisvsubsystems32.pdb not loaded

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I created a new excel vsto add-in solution in Visual Studio 2015 and enabled Native debugging. When I try to run in debug mode I end up with an exception:
[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahZI0.png)

It turns out that appvisvsubsystems32.pdb is not loaded. When I try to load it it says it can't be found @ Microsoft Symbol Servers:
[Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp02O.png)

How can I solve this?